# Get parameter from URL and redirect?

Tags: php

I'm trying to setup a PHP redirect based off a variable in the URL.  Here's my current code:

```
$afflink = $_GET['trial'];
header( 'Location: http://website.com/members/aff.php?aff=$afflink' ) ;
```

However, right now it's literally redirecting to `http://website.com/members/aff.php?aff=$afflink` instead of getting the `trial` parameter from the URL and using it in the redirect code.

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Single ' treat the string AS an actual string. Variables will be treated as are. Aka $afflink will just be $afflink as a string. Use double " if you want to use the variables value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a string is in single quotes `'`, a variable within will not be evaluated. Use doubles `"`:

```
header( "Location: http://website.com/members/aff.php?aff=$afflink" ) ;
```

Comment: Worked perfect!  Thanks for the help!  I'll mark your answer as correct in a few minutes - once StackOverflow lets me :)

Answer (score 1):

Sigle quotes are interpreted literally, so change to:

```
$afflink = $_GET['trial'];
header("Location: http://website.com/members/aff.php?aff=$afflink");
```

Or:

```
$afflink = $_GET['trial'];
header('Location: http://website.com/members/aff.php?aff=' . $afflink);
```

But for a minimum security, i suggest you to use:

```
$afflink = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'trial');
header('Location: http://website.com/members/aff.php?aff=' . $afflink);
```